# PostgreSQL: Raise a message in a function in case when there is no required output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function which helps to find a word in a movie title. For example: `find '%story%'` in a movie title.

But what if we do not have this word in the movie list? I want to raise a message like "There is no movie with the required word". How to do that with my function? What is the syntax in my case?

Here is the structure of my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION movies_to_find (IN i_title varchar(20))
RETURNS TABLE ( rows
) AS $$ 
 
    statements

$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please read the [TAG Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) of the TAG you have used and then edit your question as appropriate.

Comment: @Stu, added tag Postgres.

Comment: `raise` is part of [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) and can't be used in a SQL function. But showing such a message doesn't really make sense. It would only be visible in an interactive SQL session (and a SQL tool that supports Postgres' server side messages). It would never be visible if that function is called from within your application's code. Messages like that are better implemented in the GUI of your application.